# Formatting 500gb HDD NTFS to FAT32 then returns: The volume is too big for FAT32

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, fat32, diskpart

I got the same error message as [this post](https://superuser.com/q/293440/1878387) and it also took me 6 hours to wait for that process to finish.

But now, I already understand a little why the problem occurs after reading the answer from that post.

But now I have questions:

- Does that 6-hour formatting process that ended in failure affect the health of my HDD?
- Or can it degrade the performance of my HDD?
- Or are there any other negative side effects to my HDD?

Comment: HDDs expect to be used. If 6 hours of use was going to cause a problem then manufacturers would quickly go bankrupt. On a side note long formats are almost completely unnecessary these days, unless you expect that you have bad sectors then a quick format will do. Modern drives have an over-provisioning area where they remap failed sectors on the fly.

Comment: Wanting to format a 500GB HDD as FAT32 suggests a X-Y problem. Why exactly do you want FAT32?

Comment: I want the fat32 format because I want to use the hard disk as my internal PS3 @ChanganAuto

Comment: Ah, I see, that means it shouldn't have any effect, right? Even though previously there was a 6 hour long format process that ended in failure? @Mokubai

Comment: @Hanz I have moved my comments to an answer.

Comment: Related: [*If FAT32 is limited to 2^28 clusters, why can't I format a 250GB partition with a 1K cluster size?*](https://superuser.com/q/1699518/432690). One of the answers provides a link to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bikbJPI-7Kg), maybe you will find it interesting.

Comment: PS3 supports exFAT as well as FAT32 - https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/format-external-hard-drive-for-ps3.html - so the smart thing to do is obviously exFAT to avoid the need for 3rd party tools and to avoid the limitations of the old format that by now you should be painfully aware.

Answer (score 5):

The "failure" that you are seeing is a limitations in the built-in Windows tools which are limited to 32GB for FAT32 partitions.

As per the Microsoft page [Default cluster size for NTFS, FAT, and exFAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat-9772e6f1-e31a-00d7-e18f-73169155af95) Windows does not support creating a partition with 32KB clusters.

| Volume size | Windows NT 3.51 | Windows NT 4.0 | Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, Windows 2000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 MB–16MB | Not supported | Not supported | Not supported |
| 16 MB–32 MB | 512 bytes | 512 bytes | Not supported |
| 32 MB–64 MB | 512 bytes | 512 bytes | 512 bytes |
| 64 MB–128 MB | 1 KB | 1 KB | 1 KB |
| 128 MB–256 MB | 2 KB | 2 KB | 2 KB |
| 256 MB–8GB | 4 KB | 4 KB | 4 KB |
| 8GB–16GB | 8 KB | 8 KB | 8 KB |
| 16GB–32GB | 16 KB | 16 KB | 16 KB |
| 32GB–2TB | 32 KB | **Not supported** | **Not supported** |
| > 2TB | Not supported | Not supported | Not supported |

That doesn't mean it cannot read or write to those drives, just that the tools provided by default by Microsoft will not create them.

It is entirely a software failure, not a failure in your drive.

You should use any of the tools recommended in the answers on your linked question. Personally I recommend the tool suggested by Jeff Atwood in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/521715/19943) but just make sure to select "quick format" as a long format is only required if you suspect bad sectors on the drive and want the software to scan and mark them as such. Most modern drives should perform this duty themselves using a pool of "spare" sectors that they will automatically reallocate when bad sectors are detected.

As far as your 3 questions:

> Does that 6-hour formatting process that ended in failure affect the health of my HDD?

No. As far as the drive is concerned it was just being used normally for 6 hours.

> Or can it degrade the performance of my HDD?

No. As far as the drive is concerned it was just being used normally for 6 hours.

> Or are there any other negative side effects to my HDD?

No. As far as the drive is concerned it was just being used normally for 6 hours.

While 6 hours of use may be a long time it should be well within the operational lifespan of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

FAT32 partitions are limited to 2 TB in size, so you simply can't format
a very large disk as one FAT32 partition. You need to use a very large
sector cluster size for a large FAT32 partition in the
[format command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/format).
FAT32 cluster size can go up to 256K bytes in size (`/A` parameter).

The exFAT format is less limited, if it can be used.

However, the NTFS format is the most suitable for large disks on Windows.

Reference :
[What Is FAT32?](https://www.coursera.org/articles/fat32)