# USB cannot be accessed after using Rufus

Tags: usb, partitioning, steam, rufus, steam-os

I tried to install SteamOS Recovery on one of my USB. Half-way through I realized I made the stupidest beginner mistake---the USB size was too small. So I tried to cancel---only to crash Rufus, then my PC. After rebooting the PC, when I plug my USB, it won't connect correctly. It will show up as randomly many different disks (as partitioned ones do) but they will take turn disconnecting so I can't use anything to clean or erase it. It will just show "E connected, F connected, G connected, E disconnected, F disconnected, H connected, G disconnected, I connected" like this random connect then disconnect then connect. Any tips beside grab a huge magnet and do it...the hard way? (I jest about that option)

Comment: 1. Remove all partition using Disks, diskmgmt.msc or DiskGenius. 2. create one partition 3. Format it, likely FAT32.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rufus nor any other software can fix my 16GB usb drive after using RUFUS](https://superuser.com/questions/840827/rufus-nor-any-other-software-can-fix-my-16gb-usb-drive-after-using-rufus).  Akeo is the author of Rufus, given that they indicate this type of failure is often link to device failure, that likely is the case.  **Flash media isn't wiped by magnets, by the way so that approach wouldn't solve your problem**