# Cannot burn Ubuntu ISO into USB using Windows 8.1

Tags: usb

I am seriously lost with this simple thing. I have Windows 8.1 and want to burn ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso into USB.

Every time I format USB to FAT or FAT32, I get an error with all 3 of these software:

**Unetbootin**: `The disk cannot be written because it is write protected.`

**Universal USB installer**: `An error(1) occured when executing syslinux. Your USB drive won't be bootable.`

**Rufus2.5**: `error: write error`

I tried with 2 different USB - 2Gb and 8Gb, neither of them have any physical locks. ISO size is 1Gb.

If I format USB to NTFS file system then it works, but after it finishes, the USB is shown as completely empty. Also computer does not recognize it either while booting.

To remove write protection (if it was on), I did [this](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/storage/how-erase-write-protected-usb-drive-or-sd-card-3456666/), but nothing changed.

What am I missing, and what file system am I supposed to use when burning Ubuntu into USB?

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In windows I would ensure there are just one partition on the USB drive. See article [How to delete a partition on a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/536813/how-to-delete-a-partition-on-a-usb-drive)

Once you have cleared all partitions on USB drive, try writing your ISO to the USB again. I use [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)

Comment: My USB only have 1 partition, I checked it.